# Multiple read of register in VHDL and encapsulation leads to wrong value

Tags: vhdl, encapsulation, multiple-records

I currently confront one problem with reading two registers and send their value via proxy to tile on FPGA. There are three input channels for encoded signals which consis of pulses with frequency of 50khz, then the signal were sampled by a local 100Mhz clock on FPGA board. In the module two channels were counted for their pulses and I use  bit shift for encapsulation to put the read value from two counter into one 32bits std_bit_vector to send via proxy.

If I only transfer counting value of one channel and sent them via proxy signals, it behaviors always correctly. However when reading two counting value from two register and doing the encapsulation, the 16 higher bits of the shifted value is always increasing faster than it supposed to be. In another word, counting process ifself is correct while there is also no problems with communication between counting module and tile.

I dont know the problem is caused by the process reading too fast from two registers and leads to synchronization problem. One channel input signal only increases by one per 500 counts, while another counting 500 per rotation.One rotation is controlled by hand on the encoder (THen u can imagine the low frequency of the input signals)

THen encapsulation were put in last two lines of the module.
THanks in advance.

THe module of counting is design as following:

```
 library rdt_dtl_proxy_targetlib;
use rdt_dtl_proxy_targetlib.rdt_dtl_proxy_target_cmp_pkg.all;
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_ARITH.all; 
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;


entity dtl_pmod_rotary is
  generic (
    WIDTH_DTL_CMD_ADDR : natural:= 32;
    WIDTH_DTL_CMD_BLOCK_SIZE : natural:= 5;
    WIDTH_DTL_DATA : natural:= 32;
    WIDTH_DTL_WR_MASK : natural:= 4
  );
  port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    rst_n : in std_logic;
    rotary_a : in std_logic;
    rotary_b : in std_logic;
    rotary_i : in std_logic;
    dtl_cmd_valid_t_proxy0 : in std_logic;
    dtl_cmd_accept_t_proxy0 : out std_logic;
    dtl_cmd_addr_t_proxy0 : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_CMD_ADDR - 1 downto 0);
    dtl_cmd_read_t_proxy0 : in std_logic;
    dtl_cmd_block_size_t_proxy0 : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_CMD_BLOCK_SIZE - 1 downto 0);
    dtl_wr_valid_t_proxy0 : in std_logic;
    dtl_wr_last_t_proxy0 : in std_logic;
    dtl_wr_accept_t_proxy0 : out std_logic;
    dtl_wr_data_t_proxy0 : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA - 1 downto 0);
    dtl_wr_mask_t_proxy0 : in std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_WR_MASK - 1 downto 0);
    dtl_rd_last_t_proxy0 : out std_logic;
    dtl_rd_valid_t_proxy0 : out std_logic;
    dtl_rd_accept_t_proxy0 : in std_logic;
    dtl_rd_data_t_proxy0 : out std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA - 1 downto 0)
  );
end dtl_pmod_rotary;

architecture rtl of dtl_pmod_rotary is
  signal dtl_rd_data_15 : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA - 1 downto 0);
  signal dtl_rd_accept_14 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_cmd_block_size_6 : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_CMD_BLOCK_SIZE - 1 downto 0);
  signal dtl_wr_data_10 : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA - 1 downto 0);
  signal dtl_cmd_read_5 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_rd_last_12 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_rst_n_1 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_wr_valid_7 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_wr_accept_9 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_wr_last_8 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_cmd_addr_4 : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_CMD_ADDR - 1 downto 0);
  signal dtl_cmd_valid_2 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_clk_0 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_rd_valid_13 : std_logic;
  signal dtl_wr_mask_11 : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_WR_MASK - 1 downto 0);
  signal dtl_cmd_accept_3 : std_logic;

  -- signals for counting
  signal cnt_r         : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA-1 downto 0) := X"00000000";
  signal cnt_r_a       : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA-1 downto 0) := X"00000000";
  signal cnt_r_b       : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA-1 downto 0) := X"00000000";
  signal cnt_r_i       : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA-1 downto 0) := X"00000000";

  signal cnt_nxt_a     : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA-1 downto 0) := X"00000000";
  signal cnt_nxt_b     : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA-1 downto 0) := X"00000000";
  signal cnt_nxt_i     : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA-1 downto 0) := X"00000000";
  signal cnt_ref_i     : std_logic_vector(WIDTH_DTL_DATA-1 downto 0) := X"00000000";

  signal rotary_a_r  : std_logic;                                    --register storing data from rotary_a.
  signal rotary_a_2r : std_logic;                                    --register storing data from rotary_a_r

  signal rotary_b_r  : std_logic;                                    --register storing data from rotary_b.
  signal rotary_b_2r : std_logic;                                    --register storing data from rotary_b_r

  signal rotary_i_r : std_logic;                                    --register storing data from rotary_i.
  signal rotary_i_2r : std_logic;                                    --register storing data from rotary_i_r



  begin
  dtl_clk_0 <= clk;
  dtl_rst_n_1 <= rst_n;
  dtl_cmd_valid_2 <= dtl_cmd_valid_t_proxy0;
  dtl_cmd_accept_t_proxy0 <= dtl_cmd_accept_3;
  dtl_cmd_addr_4 <= dtl_cmd_addr_t_proxy0;
  dtl_cmd_read_5 <= dtl_cmd_read_t_proxy0;
  dtl_cmd_block_size_6 <= dtl_cmd_block_size_t_proxy0;
  dtl_wr_valid_7 <= dtl_wr_valid_t_proxy0;
  dtl_wr_last_8 <= dtl_wr_last_t_proxy0;
  dtl_wr_accept_t_proxy0 <= dtl_wr_accept_9;
  dtl_wr_data_10 <= dtl_wr_data_t_proxy0;
  dtl_wr_mask_11 <= dtl_wr_mask_t_proxy0;
  dtl_rd_last_t_proxy0 <= dtl_rd_last_12;
  dtl_rd_valid_t_proxy0 <= dtl_rd_valid_13;
  dtl_rd_accept_14 <= dtl_rd_accept_t_proxy0;
  dtl_rd_data_t_proxy0 <= dtl_rd_data_15;

-- Begin child instances

    proxy0 : rdt_dtl_proxy_target
      generic map (
        DTL_DATA_WIDTH => WIDTH_DTL_DATA,
        DTL_ADDR_WIDTH => WIDTH_DTL_CMD_ADDR,
        DTL_BLK_SIZE_WIDTH => WIDTH_DTL_CMD_BLOCK_SIZE,
        DTL_WR_MASK_WIDTH => WIDTH_DTL_WR_MASK
      )
    port map (
      dtl_clk   => dtl_clk_0,
      dtl_rst_n => dtl_rst_n_1,

      dtl_cmd_accept_t      => dtl_cmd_accept_3,
      dtl_cmd_addr_t        => dtl_cmd_addr_4,
      dtl_cmd_block_size_t  => dtl_cmd_block_size_6,
      dtl_cmd_read_t        => dtl_cmd_read_5,
      dtl_cmd_valid_t       => dtl_cmd_valid_2,

      dtl_rd_accept_t   => dtl_rd_accept_14,
      dtl_rd_data_t     => dtl_rd_data_15,
      dtl_rd_last_t     => dtl_rd_last_12,
      dtl_rd_valid_t    => dtl_rd_valid_13,

      dtl_wr_accept_t   => dtl_wr_accept_9,
      dtl_wr_data_t     => dtl_wr_data_10,
      dtl_wr_last_t     => dtl_wr_last_8,
      dtl_wr_mask_t     => dtl_wr_mask_11,
      dtl_wr_valid_t    => dtl_wr_valid_7,

      cmd_accept => '1',    --target accept handshake,input port of Proxy
      cmd_addr => open,
      cmd_block_size => open,
      cmd_read => open,     --output port of Proxy
      cmd_valid => open,    --output port of Proxy


      rd_accept   => open,          --output port of Proxy, return the accept info from initializer
      --rd_data   => x"00000003",   --test value
      rd_data     => cnt_r,         --input port of proxy, for sending the counter value
      rd_last     => '1',
      rd_valid    => '1',

      wr_accept   => '0',   --return value to Proxy indicating prepared for receiving written data from initiator
      wr_data     => open,  --receive data from Proxy that written by initializer
      wr_last     => open,
      wr_mask     => open,
      wr_valid    => open
    );

  -- Counting pulses
    -- combinatorial process
    comb_counter_process_a : process(rotary_a_r, rotary_a_2r)
    begin
      if rotary_a_r = '1' and rotary_a_2r = '0' then
          cnt_nxt_a   <= cnt_r_a + 1;
      else
          cnt_nxt_a   <= cnt_r_a;
      end if;
    end process;

    -- sequential process with synchronous reset
    seq_counter_process_a : process(clk)
    begin
      if rising_edge(clk) then
        if rst_n = '0' then
          cnt_r_a       <= (others => '0');
          rotary_a_r  <= '0';
          rotary_a_2r <= '0';
        else      
          -- registering
          cnt_r_a     <= cnt_nxt_a ;
          rotary_a_2r <= rotary_a_r;
          rotary_a_r  <= rotary_a;
      --cnt_r <= cnt_r_a(8 downto 0);
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;


    comb_counter_process_b : process(rotary_b_r, rotary_b_2r)
    begin
      if rotary_b_r = '1' and rotary_b_2r = '0' then
          cnt_nxt_b   <= cnt_r_b + 1;
      else
          cnt_nxt_b   <= cnt_r_b;
      end if;
    end process;

    -- sequential process with synchronous reset
    seq_counter_process_b : process(clk)
    begin
      if rising_edge(clk) then
        if rst_n = '0' then
          cnt_r_b       <= (others => '0');
          rotary_b_r  <= '0';
          rotary_b_2r <= '0';
        else      
          -- registering
          cnt_r_b       <= cnt_nxt_b;
          rotary_b_2r <= rotary_b_r;
          rotary_b_r  <= rotary_b;
      --cnt_r(31 downto 16) <= X"ABCD";
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;

    comb_counter_process_i : process(rotary_i_r, rotary_i_2r)
    begin
      if rotary_i_r = '1' and rotary_i_2r = '0' then
          cnt_nxt_i   <= cnt_r_i + 1;
      else
          cnt_nxt_i   <= cnt_r_i;
      end if;
    end process;

    -- sequential process with synchronous reset
    seq_counter_process_i : process(clk)
    begin
      if rising_edge(clk) then
        if rst_n = '0' then
          cnt_r_i       <= (others => '0');
          rotary_i_r  <= '0';
          rotary_i_2r <= '0';
        else      
          -- registering
          cnt_r_i       <= cnt_nxt_i;
          rotary_i_2r <= rotary_i_r;
          rotary_i_r  <= rotary_i;
      --cnt_r(15 downto 0) <= X"1234";  --the digits for cnt_r_i may change
        end if;
      end if;
    end process;

   cnt_r(31 downto 16) <= cnt_r_b(15 downto 0);
   cnt_r(15 downto 0) <= cnt_r_i(15 downto 0);  

end rtl;
```

Comment: Neither [tag:encapsulation] nor [tag:multiple-records] appear appropriate for your VHDL code example. If there are any protected data types they're not readily apparent. You don't supply the text of package `rdt_dtl_proxy_target_cmp_pkg`. There are no discernible record types (record has a specific meaning in VHDL). Your question is unclear as in the problem from your code. Can you show us the problem in waveforms, showing us inputs and incorrect values? What is `rdt_dtl_proxy_target`? Not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The sum total of publicly available information on the [Philips Semiconductor Device Transaction Level (DTL) Protocol Specification](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9FyC5.jpg). Philips is specifically excluded from the Wayback machine and there appear to be no publicly available copies of the specification (Version 2.4). We can determine `rdt_dtl_proxy_target` is a DTL Target from the port declaration for `dtl_pmod_rotary` (and of course 'target' in it's name).